Why is the main-container not responsive, while the top part ( of header) is, even though they have the same styling?
The header contains 3 parts:

first-header
second-header
main-container

All 3 of these have same styling, but as you can see in the picture the main-container is not shrinking like the other two. Also, when both the header parts are shrinking some elements like img and input still shows while h2 doesn't. Here is the repo.
Also, by responsive I mean, when decreasing the width of the viewport, this unexpected behavior is happening.
I provided similar styling to all the three parts, but one of them is behaving differently.


header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 60%;
}

.first-header,
.second-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.5fr;
  padding: 2em;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3.5fr 1.5fr;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2em;
}

.block-1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;  
}

.block-2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;  
}
<header>
  <div class="first-header">
      <div class="block-1"></div>
      <div class="block-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-header">
      <div class="block-1"></div>
      <div class="block-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
      <div class="block-1"></div>
      <div class="block-2"></div>
  </div>
</header>





I was trying to add html and css, but it was not submitting, because it was a lot (and everything was relevant), and that is why I've provided link to the repo.

I've tried to include the minimal necessary code and debugging details.

I've voted to reopen after combining your code into a single snippet so it works together. Please revise further to accurately show your problem (it seems like more colors or some text content would help). Protip: Never announce a link and then dump an ugly URL into a page. It's very unprofessional. Build a proper link with descriptive text.

You'll also want to be more clear about what "responsive" means to you. It's not a descriptive term, but more of a catch-all for "changes due to various conditions".

Issue = doing a couple of odd things with grid
TL;DR
Setting "width" and "height" values for elements (while a great idea for images and videos) will often make things more difficult when it comes to responsive design.
Horizontal issues
So all three of your div elements (first-header, second-header, and main-container) are running the entire width of the header element. If you were to give your first two div elements a background color or a border, you would see that.
Then you have the .block div elements inside your three upper-level div elements. What makes things a bit wonky is that all your upper-level div elements have display: grid; and are set to have two columns, but only your third .main-container element has two nested elements to go into each of the two columns.
When the viewport is wide enough to accommodate more space between your .main-container element's two .block div elements, you can see that the second .block is pushed way out to where your second grid column starts (I've made a code snippet below with your .block divs set to have less width so you can observe this on a not very wide viewport like we have here in StackOverflow).
Your first two upper-level div elements, of course, only look like they take up the left-most portion of their containers because you're actually only seeing the inner div elements (the .block elements). My code snippet below has a different background color for all six types of elements in question so that this is easier to see.
Later, I have a second code snippet where I don't constrain the width of the inner .block elements so that you can see where the column boundaries are (and they are right where you yourself set them with grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.5fr;).
Vertical issues
You've got some strange vertical issues going on because you constrain how much vertical space your three upper-level div elements can take up when you set grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 80%; on the header element.
Also, your grid-column: 2 / 3; setting on the header element is counter-productive. As you'll see in my code snippets, it makes more sense (at least for this minimal example) for you to not set display: grid; on the header element. If we leave it as its default display setting, then all the children elements will simply take up however much space they need to based on their content.
Code Snippets
1st Example

All different colors to see better what is happening
Less width on children .block div elements to see how the second .block in your .main-container is right out where grid is telling it to be.
got rid of style definitions on header element because there was no change without them



.first-header,
.second-header,
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.5fr;
  padding: 2em;
}
.first-header {
  background-color: green;
}
.second-header {
  background-color: black;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.block{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.block-first {
  background-color: red;
}
.block-second {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block-main {
  background-color: blue;
}
<body>
<header>
  <div class="first-header">
      <div class="block block-first"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-header">
      <div class="block block-second"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
      <div class="block block-main"></div>
      <div class="block block-main"></div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>



2nd Example

Same as first example except

Got rid of width for .block elements.
added some column-gap
changed color of second .block element in .main-container





.first-header,
.second-header,
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.5fr;
  padding: 2em;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
.first-header {
  background-color: green;
}
.second-header {
  background-color: black;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.block{
  height: 100px;
}
.block-first {
  background-color: red;
}
.block-second {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block-main {
  background-color: blue;
}
.block-main-second {
  background-color: pink;
}
<body>
<header>
  <div class="first-header">
      <div class="block block-first"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-header">
      <div class="block block-second"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
      <div class="block block-main"></div>
      <div class="block block-main-second"></div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>




Thank you for your detailed answer, but I still don't see, what's the issue. So, in my Dashboard I have nested divs in each column of all my 3 upper-level divs. header is a grid with 3 rows: first-header, second-header, main-container. All 3 of them have 2 columns. In first-header: I have first-header-left-part and first-header-right-part. In second header: I have second-header-left-part and second-header-right-part. In main-container: I have projects div and right-side-panel div.

The only difference I have is that the child divs of first-header and second-header are flexbox, while the child divs of my main-container are grid.

I just used overflow: auto in my .dashboard and added height : fit-content to my main-container and it solved all the issue. EVEN THIS "Also, when both the header parts are shrinking some elements like img and input still shows while h2 doesn't". I think the later one resolved just by overflow: auto. But I want to know why it was behaving the way it was before this. I still want want to know how everything got resolved, and is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying here.

@Shreyansh the main reason you have a big difference in behavior between .first-header/.second-header and main-container is that those first two div elements only have one child div element each yet they are defined to have two grid columns, which means they both have an empty right-hand grid column (when you define two columns for an element but then it only has one child element, there's no element to go into the second column). Your main-container element doesn't have the same apparent behavior because it does have two child div elements to go into both grid-columns.

Like I mentioned above in my comment, All 3 of them have 2 child divs (1 in each column). In first-header: I have .first-header-left-part and .first-header-right-part. In second header: I have .second-header-left-part and .second-header-right-part. In main-container: I have .projects div and .right-side-panel div.

@Shreyansh, then you should edit your question so that the code snippet reflects that (it currently does not). It's not easy for anyone on StackOverflow to help you if you don't give them representative code for the problem. Yes, a minimally reproducible example is important so that your example code is concise, but it needs to still be similar enough to the problem you're having to be useful.

I tried replicating the issue, I've made some changes, I noticed it too, thanks! However, in my code snippet it's working how its supposed to, but when I'm using the same layout in my dashboard it's not. I think I'm missing something that I can't figure out. But, my code snippet does show what layout I'm trying to use.
